# Pivotal GemFire cannot see cached data in Gfsh or Pulse

Tags: gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire

I have created a Spring Boot application with a Geode/GemFire cache.  I would like to connect to a Gfsh created Region with my Spring Boot application.  In my `application-context.xml` I'm using a `gfe:lookup-region` with an id of the Gfsh created Region.

In my Java configuration file I utilize a `LookupRegionFactoryBean` to get a reference to the externally defined Region.

In my `SpringBootApplication` bootstrap class I write to my *Repository* successfully, as I can read back all the objects that I saved.  But using the Gfsh tool or the Pulse tool I cannot see my cached data records (or the count of them that I saved.)

Could you provide some insight here?  Also, I tried using the `LocalRegionFactoryBean` too in my configuration file but that approach did not work either.

Thanks.

```
    application-context.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:gfe-data="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/gemfire"
           xmlns:gfe="http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire"
           xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/gemfire/spring-data-gemfire.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire http://www.springframework.org/schema/gemfire/spring-gemfire.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.geode"></context:component-scan>

        <util:properties id="gemfireProperties" location="context:geode.properties"/>

    <!--    <context:property-placeholder location="context:geode.properties"/>

        <bean id="log-level"><property name="log-level" value="${log-level}"/></bean>
        <bean id="mcast-port"><property name="mcast-port" value="${mcast-port}"/></bean>
        <bean id="name"><property name="name" value="${name}"/></bean>-->

        <gfe:annotation-driven/>
        <gfe-data:function-executions base-package="com.example.geode.config"/>
        <!-- Declare GemFire Cache -->
    <!--    <gfe:cache/>    -->
        <gfe:cache properties-ref="gemfireProperties"/>

        <!-- Local region for being used by the Message -->
    <!--    <gfe:replicated-region id="employee" value-constraint="com.example.geode.model.Employee" data-policy="REPLICATE"/>-->
        <gfe:lookup-region id="employee" value-constraint="com.example.geode.model.Employee" data-policy="REPLICATE"/>
    <!--        <gfe:local-region id="employee" value-constraint="com.example.geode.model.Employee" data-policy="REPLICATE"/>-->
        <!-- Search for GemFire repositories -->
        <gfe-data:repositories base-package="com.example.geode.repository"/>


    </beans>

    GeodeConfiguration.java:

    //imports not included

    @Configuration

    @ComponentScan
    @EnableCaching
    @EnableGemfireRepositories//(basePackages = "com.example.geode.repository")
    @EnableGemfireFunctions
    @EnableGemfireFunctionExecutions//(basePackages = "com.example.geode.function")

    @PropertySource("classpath:geode.properties")

    public class GeodeConfiguration {

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

        @Autowired
        private FunctionExecution functionExecution;

        @Value("${log-level}") 
        private String loglevel;
        @Value("${mcast-port}") 
        private String mcastPort; 
        @Value("${name}")
        private String name;    

        Properties gemfireProperties() {

            Properties gemfireProperties = new Properties();
            gemfireProperties.setProperty(loglevel, loglevel);
            gemfireProperties.setProperty(mcastPort, mcastPort);
            gemfireProperties.setProperty(name, name);

            return gemfireProperties;
        }  

        @Bean
        CacheFactoryBean gemfireCache() {

            return new CacheFactoryBean();
        }

        @Bean
        GemfireCacheManager cacheManager() {

            GemfireCacheManager cacheManager = new GemfireCacheManager();
            try {
                CacheFactoryBean cacheFactory = gemfireCache();
                //gemfireProperties();
                //cacheFactory.setProperties(gemfireProperties());
                cacheManager.setCache(cacheFactory.getObject()); //gemfireCache().getObject());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return cacheManager;
        }

        @Bean(name="employee")
        //@Autowired
        LookupRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee> getRegion(final GemFireCache cache) 
                throws Exception {

            //CacheTypeAwareRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee> region = new CacheTypeAwareRegionFactoryBean<>();//GenericRegionFactoryBean<> //LocalRegionFactoryBean<>();

            LookupRegionFactoryBean<String, Employee> region = new LookupRegionFactoryBean<>();//GenericRegionFactoryBean<> //LocalRegionFactoryBean<>();        

            region.setRegionName("employee");

            try {
                    region.setCache(gemfireCache().getObject());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }        
            //region.setClose(false);
            region.setName("employee");    
            //region.setAsyncEventQueues(new AsyncEventQueue[]{gemfireQueue});       
            //region.setPersistent(false);
            //region.setDataPolicy(org.apache.geode.cache.DataPolicy.REPLICATE);  //PRELOADED);   //REPLICATE);  
            region.afterPropertiesSet();

            return region;
        }

    }

    BasicGeodeApplication.java:

    //imports not provided

    @EnableGemfireRepositories
    @SpringBootApplication

    @ComponentScan("com.example.geode")
    //@EnableCaching
    @EnableGemfireCaching
    @EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = Employee.class)

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    //@CacheServerApplication(name = "server2", locators = "localhost[10334]",
    //    autoStartup = true, port = 41414)
    public class BasicGeodeApplication {

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeService employeeService;

        private static ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            context = SpringApplication.run(BasicGeodeApplication.class, args);


            BasicGeodeApplication bga = new BasicGeodeApplication();

        }

        @Bean
        public ApplicationRunner run(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {

            return args -> {

                Employee bob = new Employee("Bob", 80.0);
                Employee sue = new Employee("Susan", 95.0);
                Employee jane = new Employee("Jane", 85.0);
                Employee jack = new Employee("Jack", 90.0);

                List<Employee> employees = Arrays.asList(bob, sue, jane, jack);
                employees.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName));

                for (Employee employee : employees) {

                    //employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
                    employeeRepository.save(employee);
                }

                System.out.println("\nList of employees:");

                employees //Arrays.asList(bob.getName(), sue.getName(), jane.getName(), jack.getName());
                    .forEach(person -> System.out.println("\t" + employeeRepository.findByName(person.getName())));

                System.out.println("\nQuery salary greater than 80k:");

                stream(employeeRepository.findBySalaryGreaterThan(80.0).spliterator(), false)
                    .forEach(person -> System.out.println("\t" + person));

                System.out.println("\nQuery salary less than 95k:");

                stream(employeeRepository.findBySalaryLessThan(95.0).spliterator(), false)
                    .forEach(person -> System.out.println("\t" + person));

                System.out.println("\nQuery salary greater than 80k and less than 95k:");

                stream(employeeRepository.findBySalaryGreaterThanAndSalaryLessThan(80.0, 95.0).spliterator(), false)
                    .forEach(person -> System.out.println("\t" + person));

            };

        }


    @Service 
    class EmployeeService {   

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

        @CachePut(cacheNames = "employee", key = "#id")
        //@PutMapping("/")
        void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {

            employeeRepository.save(employee);
        }

        Employee findEmployee(String name) {

            return null;
        }
        //employeeRepository.findByName(person.getName())));
    }

    } 

    EmployeeRepository.java:


    @Repository("employeeRepository")
    //@DependsOn("gemfireCache")
    public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, String> {

        Employee findByName(String name);

        Iterable<Employee> findBySalaryGreaterThan(double salary);

        Iterable<Employee> findBySalaryLessThan(double salary);

        Iterable<Employee> findBySalaryGreaterThanAndSalaryLessThan(double salary1, double salary2);
    }



Employee.java:

// imports not included

@Entity
@Region("employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)    
    @javax.persistence.Id
    private Long id;
    public String name;
    public double salary;

    protected Employee() {}

    @PersistenceConstructor
    public Employee(String name, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " salary is: " + salary;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd be very surprised if your Spring Boot application was actually using the Region(s) created in Gfsh after attempting a lookup.  This is also evident from the fact that you cannot see data in the Region(s) when using *Gfsh* or *Pulse* after running your application.

In addition, it is not entirely apparent from your configuration whether your Spring Boot application is joining a cluster started with *Gfsh* since you have not shared the contents of your `geode.properties` file.

> NOTE: We will come back to your properties file in a moment, since how you reference it (i.e. with `context:` in the `location` attribute of the `<util>` element from the Spring `Util` schema) is not even correct.  In fact, your entire XML file is not even valid!  Bean definitions without a `class` are not valid unless they are **abstract**.

*What version of Spring Boot and Spring Data Geode/GemFire (SDG) are you using?*

Judging by the Spring XML schema references in your XML configuration file, you are using Spring 3.0!?  You should not reference versions in your schema location declarations.  An unqualified schema version will be versioned based on the Spring JARs you imported on your application classpath (e.g. using Maven).

Anyway, the reason I ask is, I have made many changes to SDG causing it to *fail-fast* in the event that the configuration is ambiguous or incomplete (for [instance](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap:region:lookup)).

In your case, the lookup would have failed instantly if the Region(s) did not exist.  And, I am quite certain the Region(s) do not exist because SDG [**disables** *Cluster Configuration*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap:cache:cluster-configuration) on a peer cache node/application, by default.  Therefore, none of the Region(s) you created in *Gfsh* are immediately available to your Spring Boot application.

So, let's walk through a simple example.  I will mostly use SDG's new [annotation configuration model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap) mixed with some Java config, for ease of use and convenience.  I encourage you to read this chapter in SDG's Reference Guide given your configuration is all over the place and I am pretty certain you confusing what is actually happening.

Here is my Spring Boot, Apache Geode application...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class ClusterConfiguredGeodeServerApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ClusterConfiguredGeodeServerApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean
  ApplicationRunner runner(GemfireTemplate customersTemplate) {

    return args -> {

      Customer jonDoe = Customer.named("Jon Doe").identifiedBy(1L);

      customersTemplate.put(jonDoe.getId(), jonDoe);
    };
  }

  @PeerCacheApplication(name = "ClusterConfiguredGeodeServerApplication")
  @EnablePdx
  static class GeodeConfiguration {

    @Bean("Customers")
    LookupRegionFactoryBean<Long, Customer> customersRegion(GemFireCache gemfireCache) {

      LookupRegionFactoryBean<Long, Customer> customersRegion = new LookupRegionFactoryBean<>();

      customersRegion.setCache(gemfireCache);

      return customersRegion;
    }

    @Bean("CustomersTemplate")
    GemfireTemplate customersTemplate(@Qualifier("Customers") Region<?, ?> customers) {
      return new GemfireTemplate(customers);
    }
  }

  @Data
  @RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName = "named")
  static class Customer {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String name;

    Customer identifiedBy(Long id) {
      this.id = id;
      return this;
    }
  }
}
```

I am using *Spring Data* `Lovelace RC1` (which includes *Spring Data for Apache Geode* `2.1.0.RC1`).  I am also using Spring Boot `2.0.3.RELEASE`, which pulls in core Spring Framework `5.0.7.RELEASE`, all on Java 8.

I ommited package and import declarations.

I am using [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to define my `Customer` class.

I have a nested `GeodeConfiguration` class to configure the Spring Boot application as a "peer" `Cache` member capable of joining an Apache Geode cluster.  However, it is not part of any cluster yet!

Finally, I have configured a "Customers" Region, which is "looked" up in the Spring context.

When I start this application, it fails because there is no "Customers" Region defined yet, by any means...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Region [Customers] in Cache [GemFireCache[id = 2126876651; isClosing = false; isShutDownAll = false; created = Thu Aug 02 13:43:07 PDT 2018; server = false; copyOnRead = false; lockLease = 120; lockTimeout = 60]] not found
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.ResolvableRegionFactoryBean.createRegion(ResolvableRegionFactoryBean.java:146) ~[spring-data-geode-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.ResolvableRegionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ResolvableRegionFactoryBean.java:96) ~[spring-data-geode-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.LookupRegionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LookupRegionFactoryBean.java:72) ~[spring-data-geode-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    ...
```

This is expected!

Alright, let's go into *Gfsh* and start a cluster.

You know that you need to start a Locator with a Server to form a cluster, right?  A Locator is used by other potential peers attempting to join the cluster so they can locate the cluster in the first place.  The Server is needed in order to create the "Customers" Region since you cannot create a Region on a Locator.

```
$ echo $GEODE_HOME
/Users/jblum/pivdev/apache-geode-1.6.0

$ gfsh
    _________________________     __
   / _____/ ______/ ______/ /____/ /
  / /  __/ /___  /_____  / _____  / 
 / /__/ / ____/  _____/ / /    / /  
/______/_/      /______/_/    /_/    1.6.0

Monitor and Manage Apache Geode

gfsh>start locator --name=LocaorOne --log-level=config
Starting a Geode Locator in /Users/jblum/pivdev/lab/LocaorOne...
....
Locator in /Users/jblum/pivdev/lab/LocaorOne on 10.0.0.121[10334] as LocaorOne is currently online.
Process ID: 41758
Uptime: 5 seconds
Geode Version: 1.6.0
Java Version: 1.8.0_152
Log File: /Users/jblum/pivdev/lab/LocaorOne/LocaorOne.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.enable-cluster-configuration=true -Dgemfire.load-cluster-configuration-from-dir=false -Dgemfire.log-level=config -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: /Users/jblum/pivdev/apache-geode-1.6.0/lib/geode-core-1.6.0.jar:/Users/jblum/pivdev/apache-geode-1.6.0/lib/geode-dependencies.jar

Successfully connected to: JMX Manager [host=10.0.0.121, port=1099]

Cluster configuration service is up and running.

gfsh>start server --name=ServerOne --log-level=config
Starting a Geode Server in /Users/jblum/pivdev/lab/ServerOne...
...
Server in /Users/jblum/pivdev/lab/ServerOne on 10.0.0.121[40404] as ServerOne is currently online.
Process ID: 41785
Uptime: 3 seconds
Geode Version: 1.6.0
Java Version: 1.8.0_152
Log File: /Users/jblum/pivdev/lab/ServerOne/ServerOne.log
JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.default.locators=10.0.0.121[10334] -Dgemfire.start-dev-rest-api=false -Dgemfire.use-cluster-configuration=true -Dgemfire.log-level=config -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -KILL %p -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
Class-Path: /Users/jblum/pivdev/apache-geode-1.6.0/lib/geode-core-1.6.0.jar:/Users/jblum/pivdev/apache-geode-1.6.0/lib/geode-dependencies.jar

gfsh>list members
  Name    | Id
--------- | --------------------------------------------------------------
LocaorOne | 10.0.0.121(LocaorOne:41758:locator)<ec><v0>:1024 [Coordinator]
ServerOne | 10.0.0.121(ServerOne:41785)<v1>:1025

gfsh>list regions
No Regions Found

gfsh>create region --name=Customers --type=PARTITION --key-constraint=java.lang.Long --value-constraint=java.lang.Object
 Member   | Status
--------- | ------------------------------------------
ServerOne | Region "/Customers" created on "ServerOne"

gfsh>list regions
List of regions
---------------
Customers

gfsh>describe region --name=Customers
..........................................................
Name            : Customers
Data Policy     : partition
Hosting Members : ServerOne

Non-Default Attributes Shared By Hosting Members  

 Type  |    Name     | Value
------ | ----------- | ---------
Region | size        | 0
       | data-policy | PARTITION
```

Now, even if I run the Spring Boot application again, it will still fail with the same Exception...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Region [Customers] in Cache [GemFireCache[id = 989520513; isClosing = false; isShutDownAll = false; created = Thu Aug 02 14:09:25 PDT 2018; server = false; copyOnRead = false; lockLease = 120; lockTimeout = 60]] not found
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.ResolvableRegionFactoryBean.createRegion(ResolvableRegionFactoryBean.java:146) ~[spring-data-geode-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.ResolvableRegionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ResolvableRegionFactoryBean.java:96) ~[spring-data-geode-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    at org.springframework.data.gemfire.LookupRegionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LookupRegionFactoryBean.java:72) ~[spring-data-geode-2.1.0.RC1.jar:2.1.0.RC1]
    ...
```

Why?

This because 1) the Spring Boot, Apache Geode peer `Cache` application is not part of the cluster (yet) and 2) because, by default, SDG does not allow a Spring configured/bootstrapped Apache Geode peer `Cache` application to get it's configuration from the cluster (specifically, from the [*Cluster Configuration Service*](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/95/geode/configuring/cluster_config/gfsh_persist.html)), therefore, we have to configure/enable both things.

We can have our Spring Boot, Apache Geode peer `Cache` application join the cluster specifically by specifying the `locators` attribute of the `@PeerCacheApplication` annotation as `localhost[10334]`.

`@PeerCacheApplication(name = "...", locators = "localhost[10334]")`

We can have our Spring Boot, Apache Geode peer `Cache` application get its configuration from the cluster by enabling the `useClusterConfiguration` property, which we do by adding the following `Configurer` bean definition to our inner, static `GeodeConfiguration` class, as follows:

```
@Bean
PeerCacheConfigurer useClusterConfigurationConfigurer() {
  return (beanName, cacheFactoryBean) -> cacheFactoryBean.setUseClusterConfiguration(true);
}
```

Now, when we run our Spring Boot, Apache Geode peer `Cache` application again, we see quite different output.  First, see that our peer member (app) gets the cluster configuration...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<cache xmlns="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" copy-on-read="false" is-server="false" lock-lease="120" lock-timeout="60" search-timeout="300" version="1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache/cache-1.0.xsd">

<region name="Customers">
    <region-attributes data-policy="partition">
      <key-constraint>java.lang.Long</key-constraint>
      <value-constraint>java.lang.Object</value-constraint>
    </region-attributes>
  </region>
</cache>
```

Next, you may have noticed that I enabled PDX, using SDG's `@EnablePdx` annotation.  This allows us to easily serialize our application domain model object types (e.g. `Customer`) without our type unduly needing to implement `java.io.Serializable`.  There are several reasons why you wouldn't necessarily want to implement `java.io.Serializable` anyway.  Using SDG's `@EnablePdx` uses SDG's [`MappingPdxSerializer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.pdx-serializer) implementation, which is far more powerful than even Apache Geode's/Pivotal GemFire's own `ReflectionBasedAutoSerializer`.

As result of serializing the application types (namely, `Customer`), you will see this output...

```
14:26:48.322 [main] INFO  org.apache.geode.internal.cache.PartitionedRegion - Partitioned Region /Customers is created with prId=2
Started ClusterConfiguredGeodeServerApplication in 4.223 seconds (JVM running for 5.574)
14:26:48.966 [main] INFO  org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.PeerTypeRegistration - Adding new type: PdxType[dsid=0, typenum=14762571
        name=example.app.spring.cluster_config.server.ClusterConfiguredGeodeServerApplication$Customer
        fields=[
        id:Object:identity:0:idx0(relativeOffset)=0:idx1(vlfOffsetIndex)=-1
        name:String:1:1:idx0(relativeOffset)=0:idx1(vlfOffsetIndex)=1]]
14:26:49.002 [main] INFO  org.apache.geode.pdx.internal.TypeRegistry - Caching PdxType[dsid=0, typenum=14762571
        name=example.app.spring.cluster_config.server.ClusterConfiguredGeodeServerApplication$Customer
        fields=[
        id:Object:identity:0:idx0(relativeOffset)=0:idx1(vlfOffsetIndex)=-1
        name:String:1:1:idx0(relativeOffset)=0:idx1(vlfOffsetIndex)=1]]
```

Another reason I enable PDX is so that I do not need to add the `Customer` class to the Server (i.e. "`ServerOne`") started using *Gfsh*.  It also allows me to query the "Customers" Region and see that `Customer` "Jon Doe" was successfully added...

```
gfsh>describe region --name=Customers
..........................................................
Name            : Customers
Data Policy     : partition
Hosting Members : ServerOne

Non-Default Attributes Shared By Hosting Members  

 Type  |    Name     | Value
------ | ----------- | ---------
Region | size        | 1
       | data-policy | PARTITION


gfsh>
gfsh>query --query="SELECT c.name FROM /Customers c"
Result : true
Limit  : 100
Rows   : 1

Result
-------
Jon Doe
```

Bingo!  Success!

I am not going to even begin to discuss everything that is wrong with your configuration.  I implore you to [read the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/reference/html/) (and Apache Geode's [User Guide](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/16/developing/book_intro.html); i.e. appropriate sections), understand the concepts, look at [examples](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application), [guides](https://spring.io/guides), ask concise questions, etc, etc.

Here is the example source code...

https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/configuration-example/src/main/java/example/app/spring/cluster_config/server/ClusterConfiguredGeodeServerApplication.java

Hope this helps!

-j